# SwitchPreference layout not correct until tapped on

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-support-library, android-preferences

I'm using `PreferenceFragmentCompat` from the Android Support Library and I've encountered a weird issue. When the fragment loads, the switches on the `SwitchPreference` elements that I am using show up right next to the text, which is the wrong place. If I tap on one switch or scroll so that the switch is out of view, it fixes itself. Note: this occurs on API 25, but not API 18.

On load:

[image: Switches in incorrect position]

After tap or scroll:

[image: Switches in correct position]

Have any thoughts on what is going on? Any help is appreciated!

Here is what I have done:

1. Switched over to `SwitchPreferenceCompat`
2. Changed (and ultimately removed) custom themes in **styles.xml**
3. Created a smaller set of switches that doesn't fill the screen. What's interesting is that if the screen isn't filled with preferences, the layout looks great.
4. Called `invalidate()` on the Fragment's view to force a redraw (hoping it would work like scrolling does to fix it)
5. Added a bunch of spaces to the text to force it to be the full width which didn't work (though actually text like a bunch of periods ...... does works lol)

**Code to create preferences (in Kotlin):**

```
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(bundle: Bundle?, s: String?) {
        val deviceCategory = PreferenceCategory(activity)
        deviceCategory.title = activity.getString(R.string.preferences_Device_Defaults)
        preferenceScreen.addPreference(deviceCategory)

        val clockPref = SwitchPreference(activity)
        clockPref.title = activity.getString(R.string.preferences_Automatic_clock_synchronization)
        clockPref.isChecked = true
        clockPref.key = "clockSync"
        deviceCategory.addPreference(clockPref)

        // Add more preferences....

        val unitCategory = PreferenceCategory(activity)
        unitCategory.title = activity.getString(R.string.preferences_Unit_Defaults)
        preferenceScreen.addPreference(unitCategory)

        val runCellTestOnConnect = SwitchPreference(activity)
        runCellTestOnConnect.title = activity.getString(R.string.preferences_Cell_network_check)
        runCellTestOnConnect.isChecked = true
        runCellTestOnConnect.key = "runCellTestOnConnect"
        unitCategory(runCellTestOnConnect)

        // Add more preferences....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I met exactly the same issue when developing in Kotlin. Currently I have a temporary workaround: creating an empty preference before all the other preferences, and filling a long invisible string in its summary.

For example, assume that I'm using a XML file to construct the preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:key="pref_static_field_key"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:selectable="false"
        android:summary="@string/spaces" />
    <!-- Other Preferences -->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then you will notice that the width of the following SwitchPreference elements are determined by the width of this empty Preference. If the "@string/spaces" is long enough (e.g. multiple lines or at least as long as the whole screen), you can get correct width.